# Lightswitch- Using Lightswitch Controls in a Custom Silverlight Control

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I am new to lightswitch and I am currently task to create a custom control in silverlight, I want to ask if it is possible to use existing lightswitch control like the date time control in my custom silverlight control?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any Silverlight control BUT the datetime control. For some reason I have never been able to make that one work with LightSwitch.

See the top of this page for FREE videos on creating Silverlight Controls with LightSiwtch: http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Market/Books/CreatingVisualStudioLightSwitchCustomControlsBeginnertoIntermediate.aspx

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for example we bought a third party lightswitch WYSIWYG control can I include that control on my custom silverlight control? Thanks

Comment: I have examples of that here: http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/tagid/2/Custom-Controls.aspx

Comment: Thanks, you website is really a big help :)